# Do I need to use a temporary value for this assignment?

Tags: c++

I inherited some code containing the following passage:

```
TStringList* pPortList(NULL);
pPortList = FindCommPorts();
ConnectionDialog->PortList = pPortList;
int nModalReturn = ConnectionDialog->ShowModal();
delete pPortList;
```

`FindCommPorts()` is a function that creates a `new TStringList()`, populates it, and returns it.

I was tempted to replace the code with this:

```
ConnectionDialog->PortList = FindCommPorts();
int nModalReturn = ConnectionDialog->ShowModal();
```

but then I realized I'm not familiar enough with C++'s ownership semantics to be sure about this. Will this leak memory because the result of `FindCommPorts()` is never `delete`d?

**Edit:** Looking through the code again, I don't think that the original version resulted in a hanging pointer--it turns out that `ConnectionDialog->PortList` is actually a property (I'm using Borland C++Builder 6). This property has a custom setter that copies the strings out of the `TStringList`, and the passed pointer itself is not used after that. I apologize for not mentioning this earlier--the way the code was written, it definitely looked bad.

Comment: I dunno, but the code you inherited already seems to be having a dangling pointer `ConnectionDialog->PortList` will be one after the call to `delete pPortList`.

Comment: I's sure hope that the code isn't designed such that it would cause a memory leak

Comment: Did the next statement in the original code happen to be `ConnectionDialog->PortList = NULL;` or `delete ConnectionDialog;`?

Comment: @bdesham: Does `ConnectionDialog->ShowModel()` also set `ConnectionDialog->PortList` to `nullptr` or `NULL`?

Comment: The `PortList` is never explicitly set to `NULL`, but see my edit to the question. Thanks to Borland, this code doesn't quite do what it seems to...

Comment: an exception could let that code leak that bit of memory though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is never `delete`d, then yes you will leak memory. However, the problem that you have with this code is even worse. Think of your situation like this:

- `FindCommPorts()` returns a pointer
- You tell `ConnectionDialog->PortList` to point to the same memory that `FindCommPorts()` result pointed to.
- You then `delete` the object at the memory that `pPortList` points to, **which is the same as the memory that `ConnectionDialog->PortList` points to!**

After this, The `PortList` variable points to deleted memory, and you should not access it.  If you will ever need to use this pointer again, you should not be deleting it anyway, so you don't have to worry about assigning the result of `FindCommPorts()` directly to `ConnectionDialog->PortList`. Just make sure to delete it when you're done with it.

If you will need that pointer to be valid forever, then this situation is not a memory leak because the data is needed. In that case, the memory will be freed when the program terminates.

**EDIT**

After reading the edit to your question, I see that you are right. You do need the temporary variable in order to prevent a memory leak. If you don't do this, the property's setter will make a copy of the object pointed to by the pointer returned by `FindCommPorts()`, and then the memory will remain allocated, but with no variable containing a pointer pointing to it. In this case, you are right to make the temporary variable, and then to delete it after doing the assignment.